# Can't grab $_GET from CURL POST in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, post, get

I've been fighting for the past couple hours with a weird issue on my local and I'm all out of ideas.

I'm trying to setup a local webhook and grab $_GET values from it. It works fine when I type the url in the address bar and hit enter ie.

```
http://my-local.com/something/?foo=bar
```

It does not work at all when I try to do the same directly via CURL or wp_remote_post.
I've tried to use CURL both in PHP and Terminal and both don't work. The CURL call returns status 200 OK and the HTML of the site so it's working and it's not being blocked in any way, but it doesn't trigger my PHP code where I check for the $_GET.

```
$args = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => 30,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.1',
    'blocking' => true,
    'headers' => array("Content-Type" => "application/json"),
    'body' => json_encode('foo'),
    'cookies' => array(),
    'sslverify' => false
);

$res = wp_remote_post('http://my-local.com/something/?foo=bar', $args);
```

I'm all out of ideas.

Things I've tried:

- Switching from PHP 7.3 -> 7.2
- HTTP and HTTPS
- Terminal CURL
- PHP CURL
- WordPress wp_remote_post
- 127.0.0.1/localhost/my-domain.com
- Remote CURL from a webserver -> my local
- Set `Expect: ''` in CURL headers

Nothing.

The PHP logs don't show any errors and I'm not sure what is wrong with my local.

PHP 7.3.19

I'm also using reverse proxy on my Synology and I'm wondering if this can have anything to do with it?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: [wp_remote_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/) - Performs an HTTP request using the **POST** method and returns its response.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I still need the POST data, but I want to execute the PHP code only when the certain $_GET data is present and I can't do that with wp_remote_post or CURL. LIke I said, it works just fine when I manually type the url in the browser, it doesn't at all when I use the same url in wp_remote_post or CURL.

Comment: Ok, so as it turns out you need a different approach when you want to debug Webhooks on your local. I was able to get what I need using `ngrok` software. You can find more info under this useful url: https://developer.github.com/webhooks/configuring/